# Facebook App Invite using Unity

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to integrate Facebook App Invite in my Unity project, and most of it is working. I am able to send invites and also reading the data via Applink.

My question is, how do I identify the person who sent the invite in the app? I want to award some credits to the person who invited for which I need some identity of the person in the app so that I can award them credits using some server side logic.

Can I pass some referral code or get some Facebook id to track the person who sends the invite?

I am using Facebook Unity SDK 7.2.

Answer (score 1):

With [App Invites](https://developers.intern.facebook.com/products/sharing/app-invites) you can pass through any custom referral data you wish, but you need to build a small bit of infrastructure to support it.

With each app invite you add a App Link URL. These App Links are essentially empty html pages with special metadata. [Example markup here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios#app_links)

Within the AppLink metadata, you append deeplinking information to the platform urls (al:ios:url / al:android:url)

For example:

```
<meta property="al:ios:url" content="couchinapp://invite_from_fb?referral=123456789" />
<meta property="al:android:url" content="couchinapp://invite_from_fb?referral=123456789" />
```

Where referral is an extra parameter you append with any information you want to append to the invite (sender id, referral code, clan to join, where to take them in the app, etc)

You could use the [AppLinksTool](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=app-links-host) to create static App Links, but these will not support dynamic parameters. We need to create a small system to return the correct AppLink metadata with your deep-linking information.

---

Okay so, with that background... Instead of hosting static html pages with content… create a dynamic page ([as described here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios#dynamic_endpoint)) to return a formatted AppLink based on what you parameters pass to the endpoint.

For example:

```
Endpoint:    
https://myapp.com/applink?referral=123abc

Returns:
...
<meta property="al:ios:url" content="couchinapp://invite_from_fb?referral=123abc" />
...
```

Now when a new player opens your app, you can fetch the AppLink data (On Unity:  [FB.Mobile.FetchDeferredAppLinkData](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.Mobile.FetchDeferredAppLinkData)) to retrieve the relevant platform URL to see if they came in through an App Invite and then you can take action based on what parameters you passed in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use request_id as referral code.

In my case, I use AppRequest API, which it can read all request_id.

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/me/apprequests?access_token=[USER ACCESS TOKEN]
```

Then, you can identify both sender and receiver by

```
GET http://apps.facebook.com/[app_name]/?request_ids=[REQUEST_IDs]
```

or

```
GET http://graph.facebook.com/<REQUEST_OBJECT_ID>?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

You can find how to implement app request information here. [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.5)

Comment: Yes, but this is using AppRequests and not AppInvites. Through App Invites, you do not get any request_id when you send an invite. Only a callback with didcomplete is received. App Invite is a preferred way for mobile-only products.

Comment: Probably the answer is using custom url schemes. Currently we are using facebook hosted applink uri, but not sure how exactly it works.