# Error while trying to invite friends from Facebook on Unity3D

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm trying to invite friends from a Unity3D application but when I'm using a non fb.net/xxxxxxx facebook self hosted app link, aways get this error:

**Missing App Link URL
The app link used with this invite does not contain an Android or iOS URL. Developers are required to enter a URL for at least one platform.**

Tried to configure the page like the answer above, but it didn't worked
[Facebook App Invite using Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33258081/facebook-app-invite-using-unity/33355044#33355044)

This is my App link HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>App Link</title>
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="111111111111"/>
    <meta property="al:ios:url" content="myapp://invite_from_fb?referral=123456"/>
    <meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="MyApp"/>
    <meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="111111111111"/>
    <meta property="al:web:should_fallback" content="false"/>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/redirectToContent?id=1111111111"/>
</head>
<body>
    Redirecting...
</body>
</html>
```

I need the applink to be hosted by my because the referral id is dynamically generated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does facebook scraper debugger say?

Comment: The scrapper shows only warnings about missing og:title, og:description, etc

Answer (score 0):

I figured out whats is causing this issue:

On Facebook Settings-> App Link Schemes, I was using "myapp://", the correct way is just "myapp".

I'ts working normally now.